# How does Python calculate this formula?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this problem and I know it is correct but I am not sure how the formula works.

```
    balance: int = 484
    monthlyPayRate: float = 0.04
    annualInterestRate: float = .2
    for i in range(12):
        balance = balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate) +\
        ((balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)) * \
        (annualInterestRate/12))
    print("Remaining balance:", round(balance,2))
```

I am just trying to work through the range(1) and I know the correct answer is 472.38.

This is how I would calculate it:
484 – (484 * 0.04) = $464.64 (This is balance after payment but before interest)
464 * (.2/12) = $7.42(We took our remaining balance of 464.64 x the interest rate of 0.016)
464 .64 + 7.424 = $472 (We added our interest on our remaining balance to get our new balance)

When I try to plug the numbers into the python formula and do it by hand I cannot figure out how Python is getting it to work. I was hoping someone would be so kind as to show me the steps Python takes using the formula?

Comment: but this formula is run 12 times in a loop. the new `balance` value is used at each iteration.

Comment: Okay, so reading your description on how you would calculate it: that is _literally_ what the code is doing at each iteration, and it runs 12 times in a row. Where does what the code does, and how you compute things by hand, actually differ?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it does it like this:

```
balance = 484 - (484 * 0.04) + ((484- (484 *0.04)) * (0.2/12))
```

that is basically what it's written there, and the result is 472.38.

But then it substitutes 472.38 to the variable `balance` e does the calculation again, 12 times, always replacing the variable with the new result, returning `361.61` in the end.

The calculations worked for me both in the software and by hand.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity:

```
balance = 484
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
annualInterestRate = .2
for i in range(12):
    paidoff = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
    newinterest = (balance - paidoff) * annualInterestRate/12
    balance = balance - paidoff + newinterest
    print("Balance after", i+1, "months", round(balance,2));

print("Remaining balance:", round(balance,2))
```

gives:

```
Balance after 1 months 472.38
Balance after 2 months 461.05
Balance after 3 months 449.98
Balance after 4 months 439.18
Balance after 5 months 428.64
Balance after 6 months 418.35
Balance after 7 months 408.31
Balance after 8 months 398.51
Balance after 9 months 388.95
Balance after 10 months 379.62
Balance after 11 months 370.5
Balance after 12 months 361.61

Remaining balance: 361.61
```

Splitting the calculation allows for this sort of thing:

```
>>> balance = 484
>>> totalpaid=0
>>> totalinterest=0
>>> monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
>>> annualInterestRate = .2
>>> for i in range(12):
...     paidoff = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
...     newinterest = (balance - paidoff) * annualInterestRate/12
...     balance = balance - paidoff + newinterest
...     totalpaid = totalpaid + paidoff
...     totalinterest = totalinterest + newinterest
...
>>> print("Remaining balance:", round(balance,2))
Remaining balance: 361.61
>>> print("Total amount paid off:", round(totalpaid,2))
Total amount paid off: 203.98
>>> print("Total interest accrued:", round(totalinterest,2))
Total interest accrued: 81.59
```